# Base 64 encode a JSON variable in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, base64

I have a variable that stores json value. I want to base64 encode it in Python. But the error 'does not support the buffer interface' is thrown. I know that the base64 needs a byte to convert. But as I am newbee in Python, no idea as how to convert json to base64 encoded string.Is there a straight forward way to do it??

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Python 3.x you need to convert your `str` object to a `bytes` object for `base64` to be able to encode them. You can do that using the `str.encode` method:

```
>>> import json
>>> import base64
>>> d = {"alg": "ES256"} 
>>> s = json.dumps(d)  # Turns your json dict into a str
>>> print(s)
{"alg": "ES256"}
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> base64.b64encode(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/base64.py", line 56, in b64encode
    raise TypeError("expected bytes, not %s" % s.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: expected bytes, not str
>>> base64.b64encode(s.encode('utf-8'))
b'eyJhbGciOiAiRVMyNTYifQ=='
```

If you pass the output of `your_str_object.encode('utf-8')` to the `base64` module, you should be able to encode it fine.

Comment: My apologies if my question is ambiguous. actually I am trying to construct a JWS and encode it in Base64. So my variable is like this,           header = {"alg": "ES256"}. What I am try to do is base64.b64encode(header).

Comment: the only solution I found it work to transform an already string but encoded in base64 to plain text string. Thanks!

Comment: Have to `import base64` first

Comment: @greg Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two methods worked on python3
**encodestring** is deprecated and suggested one to use is **encodebytes**

```
import json
import base64


with open('test.json') as jsonfile:
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
    print(type(data))  #dict
    datastr = json.dumps(data)
    print(type(datastr)) #str
    print(datastr)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(datastr.encode('utf-8'))  #1 way
    print(encoded)

    print(base64.encodebytes(datastr.encode())) #2 method
```

Answer (score 2):

You could encode the string first, as UTF-8 for example, then base64 encode it:

```
data = '{"hello": "world"}'
enc = data.encode()  # utf-8 by default
print base64.encodestring(enc)
```

This also works in 2.7 :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that you can feed a string and it will output a base64 string.

```
import base64
def b64EncodeString(msg):
    msg_bytes = msg.encode('ascii')
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(msg_bytes)
    return base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
```